# Push values into a 2d vector then iterate through it

Tags: c++, vector, multidimensional-array, iterator

I have a file with data in it. The data's location is important in respect to what row they are in. There can be  multiple columns of data. After I store every value into a vector I try to put that data into another 2D vector so I can use it later and more organized. I tried to iterate through the code where I do this but I'm not sure if the problem is when I'm storing the data in a 2D vector or when i'm trying to iterate through the 2D vector.

```
columns = numOfValues / rows;

int count = 1;
vector<double> temp;
for(vector<double>::iterator it = data.begin(); it != data.end(); ++it)
{
    temp.push_back(*it);
    if (count == columns){
        allData.push_back(temp);
        temp.clear();
        count = 1;
    }
    count++;
}

int q, w = 0;
for(vector<vector<double> >::iterator i = allData.begin(); i != allData.end(); ++i){
    q++;
    cout << "upper vec: " << q << endl;
    for(vector<double>::iterator j = i->begin(); j != i->end(); ++j){
        w++;
        cout << "lower vec: " << w << endl;
        cout<< "2d vect values" << *j << endl;
    }
}
```

My problem is that when I try to access the data through the iterator none of the data is in the right place, and when it is a one column set of data, it only prints out the first value and stops. I can't seem to see a pattern in how the data is being printed out as it is now.
If anyone has an idea where the problem might be I'd greatly appreciate it. Thanks

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking.

Comment: Sorry I'll fix it, thanks.

Comment: Why copy to a jagged vector at all? You can just index by `temp[x+y*columns]`

Comment: It's quite hard to know what you are trying to do, but a good thing to check with vectors and the use of pointers/references/iterators is whether reallocation is happening. Ie. if you are doing push_backs etc. there is no guarantee the iterators are valid unless you reserve the memory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error in the first loop is that you increment `count` also when you start a new row, so one way to fix that error would be to write

```
if (count == columns){
     // ...
}
else {
    count++;
}
```

On a side note, you forget to initialize the variable `q`, plus you should check whether `numOfValues` is divisible by `rows`.